# if....else executing in the same time . Looking this problem for first time. Please anybody make me understand

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I was solving a problem . Where i was comparing two array ,one is int and other is string .
inside for loop everything was fine until i inserted a else condition.Before else condition for loop was just fine . it was giving equel index for two array . But after else condition it was giving both the condition together.
here are my code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int last_digit[] = {61, 71, 11, 21, 32, 19, 27, 31};
 string places[] = {"Brasilia", "Salvador", "Sao Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Juiz de Fora",                       "Campinas", "Vitoria", "Balo Horizonte"};
int digit;
 cin >> digit;
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
 {
 if (digit == last_digit[i])
cout << places[i]<< endl;
 else
cout << "Sorry! no number." << endl;
}
```

Now i want to print the array values as index which is right without the else condition. But i when an input isn't in the array the program should give else condition once. But it is giving both if else condition. Here are my output .

```
emamulhaqueemon@Emams-MacBook-Air snake % cd "/Users/emamulhaqueemon/main/snake/" && g++ test.cpp -o test && "/Use
rs/emamulhaqueemon/main/snake/"test
11
Sorry! no number.
emamulhaqueemon@Emams-MacBook-Air snake %
```

now why this is happening and how can i make this right .Please anybody give the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop currently does too much:

- find `digit` in `last_digit`
- print corresponding element according to found `digit`
- print no matching elements (whereas you want to print when find fails).

You might split that in smaller parts.

With functions from std, you might do:

```
const auto it = std::find(std::begin(last_digit), std::end(last_digit), digit);

if (it == std::end(last_digit)) { // Not found
    std::cout << "Sorry! no number." << std::endl;
} else { // Found
    const auto index = std::distance(std::begin(last_digit), it);
    std::cout << places[index] << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f6eaa3dbe2be570)

Answer (score 0):

Just place the output statement in the else part of the if statement outside the for loop. For example

```
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
{
    if ( digit == last_digit[i])
    {
        found = true;
        cout << places[i]<< endl;
    }
}
 
if ( !found )
{
    cout << "Sorry! no number." << endl;
}
```

If the array `last_digit` does not contain duplicate values and you need to find only the first occurrence of the value digit in the array then the loop can look the following way

```
for (int i = 0; !found && i <= 7; i++)
{
    if ( digit == last_digit[i])
    {
        found = true;
        cout << places[i]<< endl;
    }
}
 
if ( !found )
{
    cout << "Sorry! no number." << endl;
}
```